# How to draw a line between two divs?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to draw a diagonal line between the bottom right corner of one div to the top right corner of another. If possible, I would like to do it without jQuery. Is this possible?

Comment: What browsers do you want to support?  Where are these divs positioned in relation to one another?

Comment: do you any specific issues you are having trouble with? if not, I'll refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-draggable-divs which seems like the same question with the addition of draggable elements, which you can ignore.

Comment: Use SVG to draw lines ... It is much easier ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/35493651/5947203

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a line between two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-divs)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cnmsc1tm/

This won't work with IE8 or below because of CSS limitations.

```
function getOffset( el ) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        left: rect.left + window.pageXOffset,
        top: rect.top + window.pageYOffset,
        width: rect.width || el.offsetWidth,
        height: rect.height || el.offsetHeight
    };
}

function connect(div1, div2, color, thickness) { // draw a line connecting elements
    var off1 = getOffset(div1);
    var off2 = getOffset(div2);
    // bottom right
    var x1 = off1.left + off1.width;
    var y1 = off1.top + off1.height;
    // top right
    var x2 = off2.left + off2.width;
    var y2 = off2.top;
    // distance
    var length = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1) * (x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1) * (y2-y1)));
    // center
    var cx = ((x1 + x2) / 2) - (length / 2);
    var cy = ((y1 + y2) / 2) - (thickness / 2);
    // angle
    var angle = Math.atan2((y1-y2),(x1-x2))*(180/Math.PI);
    // make hr
    var htmlLine = "<div style='padding:0px; margin:0px; height:" + thickness + "px; background-color:" + color + "; line-height:1px; position:absolute; left:" + cx + "px; top:" + cy + "px; width:" + length + "px; -moz-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -o-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -ms-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg);' />";
    //
    // alert(htmlLine);
    document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine;
}
```

- The Distance Formula
- Finding the Center Of Two Points
- Finding the Angle Between Two Points
- CSS Transform:Rotate
- HTML Element offset[Width|Height|Top|Left] properties

**Edit (for others with the same problem)**:

If you need to, for example, create a line from two corners that are not the top right and bottom right divs, go to this section of the code:

```
// bottom right
var x1 = off1.left + off1.width;
var y1 = off1.top + off1.height;
// top right
var x2 = off2.left + off2.width;
var y2 = off2.top;
```

where you see `+ off1.width` and `+ off1.height`, that means that the code is calculating the position of the bottom or the right of the div. Remove the `+ off1.width` or the `+ off1.height` to get the left or the top of the div.

**EDIT** updated to a more standard getOffset function. If you want to get really anal you'd probably also have to add document.documentElement.client[Left/Top] and walk the offsetParent tree, but I think getBoundingClientRect() and window.page[X/Y]Offset are sufficient for an example like this.

Comment: that's a neat solution to avoid libraries completely, although it's too bad it won't work in IE.

Comment: The getOffset function seems to be flawed as it didn't work in with a bunch of overlapping absolutely positioned divs. I replaced get offset with the jQuery offset/height/width functions and this worked. 
        return { top: $(el).offset().top, left:$(el).offset().left, width: $(el).width(), height: $(el).height() };

Comment: Awasome answer thanks. Note if you are using jQuery, $("body").append(htmlLine) should be used instead of "document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine;" at the end of the function to avoid canvas issues (like with flot).

Comment: @louisricci thanks for the post and sharing your calc function. I would love to adopt it for my project, but whenever I try to call `connect()` I receive an error: `el.getBoundingClientRect() is not a function`. Can you help me out?

Comment: @MarianRick - Use the JSFiddle link at the top of the answer and look at how the *connect()* function is being called *window.testIt = function()*. The error you are getting suggests you are not passing valid HTML elements as the first two parameters to *connect*. If you are using *document.getElementById* to get the elements you may have mistyped the *ID* attribute or perhaps your JavaScript is executing in the *HEAD* of your page before the *BODY* (and it's HTML elements have rendered). Hope you can figure it out, good luck.

Comment: Works nicely, *except* that last line: document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine;
which seems to mess up other handlers. Instead let div = document.createElement("div"); div.style.cssText = all the style stuff; document.body.appendChild(div) seems OK

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it without jQ.

1. Find the position of your divs using offset.
2. Find the slope
3. draw `1x1px` points from start to end position using the slope in your loop.