# What could I use to join two divs through a line like so?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve, perhaps with several more objects:

[image]

It is important that the two blocks be divs, so I'm not really looking for a drawing library that would help me receive something like that picture.

Any direction on what I could use?

Comment: @Asad From the OP, "It is important that the two blocks be divs"

Comment: @Louis93: I am working on your solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672369/how-to-draw-a-line-between-two-divs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a line between two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-divs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html). It should cover what you need, and then some.

Comment: That is a nice library!

Comment: Very solid. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LqFAX/1004/ (messed up but a good try)
[image]

Another library: http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html
[image]

Yes you can draw lines using CSS3. Here's a nice starting point.

**HTML
**

```
 <div class="div1"></div>
<div style="border-top: 1px solid #000; margin-top: 40px;"></div>
<div class="div2"><div>
```

**CSS**

```
    div, hr {
     -moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
       -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
      -ms-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
          transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
             filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand',  
                      M11=0.9914448613738104, M12=-0.13052619222005157,M21=0.13052619222005157, M22=0.9914448613738104); 
         -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9914448613738104, M12=-0.13052619222005157, M21=0.13052619222005157, M22=0.9914448613738104,sizingMethod='auto expand')"; 

               zoom: 1;
}


.div1 { width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red; }
.div2 { left:160%; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:orange; }
```