# How to connect HTML Divs with Lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my page I have a set of div elements that should be connected with lines like I showed in the image below. I know that with a canvas I can draw lines between these elements, but is it possible to do it in another way in html/css?

[image]

Comment: You asked is it possible, i will say yes but using css i will say no

Comment: maybe http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/home/jquery.html

Comment: I think this sort of stuff should be definately left to SVG . Mostly because as this can be created using CSS hacks but the site will become unresposive in mobile devices

Comment: Please refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35493737/5947203

Answer (score 90):

You can use SVGs to connect two divs using only HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="div1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top:0; left:0; background:#777; position:absolute;"></div>
<div id="div2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top:300px; left:300px; background:#333; position:absolute;"></div>
```

*(please use seperate css file for styling)*

Create a svg line and  use this line to connect above divs

```
<svg width="500" height="500"><line x1="50" y1="50" x2="350" y2="350" stroke="black"/></svg>
```

where,

x1,y1 indicates center of first div and 
x2,y2 indicates center of second div

You can check how it looks in the snippet below

```html
<div id="div1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top:0; left:0; background:#777; position:absolute;"></div>
<div id="div2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top:300px; left:300px; background:#333; position:absolute;"></div>

<svg width="500" height="500"><line x1="50" y1="50" x2="350" y2="350" stroke="black"/></svg>
```

Comment: PS: for moving div's, you might want your `line` to update coordinates accordingly. But for that you will have to use JavaScript/JQuery. Visit this link to know how to do it ->    https://stackoverflow.com/a/35493737/5947203

Answer (score 53):

[I made something like this to my project](https://jsfiddle.net/rdamasceno/o3Lroapa/5/)

```js
function adjustLine(from, to, line){

  var fT = from.offsetTop  + from.offsetHeight/2;
  var tT = to.offsetTop    + to.offsetHeight/2;
  var fL = from.offsetLeft + from.offsetWidth/2;
  var tL = to.offsetLeft   + to.offsetWidth/2;
  
  var CA   = Math.abs(tT - fT);
  var CO   = Math.abs(tL - fL);
  var H    = Math.sqrt(CA*CA + CO*CO);
  var ANG  = 180 / Math.PI * Math.acos( CA/H );

  if(tT > fT){
      var top  = (tT-fT)/2 + fT;
  }else{
      var top  = (fT-tT)/2 + tT;
  }
  if(tL > fL){
      var left = (tL-fL)/2 + fL;
  }else{
      var left = (fL-tL)/2 + tL;
  }

  if(( fT < tT && fL < tL) || ( tT < fT && tL < fL) || (fT > tT && fL > tL) || (tT > fT && tL > fL)){
    ANG *= -1;
  }
  top-= H/2;

  line.style["-webkit-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
  line.style["-moz-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
  line.style["-ms-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
  line.style["-o-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
  line.style["-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
  line.style.top    = top+'px';
  line.style.left   = left+'px';
  line.style.height = H + 'px';
}
adjustLine(
  document.getElementById('div1'), 
  document.getElementById('div2'),
  document.getElementById('line')
);
```

```css
#content{
  position:relative;
}
.mydiv{
  border:1px solid #368ABB;
  background-color:#43A4DC;
  position:absolute;
}
.mydiv:after{
  content:no-close-quote;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  background-color:black;
  width:4px;
  height:4px;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-left:-2px;
  margin-top:-2px;
}
#div1{
  left:200px;
  top:200px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
#div2{
  left:20px;
  top:20px;
  width:50px;
  height:40px;
}
#line{
  position:absolute;
  width:1px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
  

<div id="content">
  <div id="div1" class="mydiv"></div>
  <div id="div2" class="mydiv"></div>
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use https://github.com/musclesoft/jquery-connections. This allows you connect block elements in DOM.

Answer (score 18):

It's kind of a pain to position, but you could use `1px` wide divs as lines and position and rotate them appropriately.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbaBG/1

```
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>
<div class="box" id="box3"></div>

<div class="line" id="line1"></div>
<div class="line" id="line2"></div>
```

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
.line {
    width: 1px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
}
#box1 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#box2 {
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
}
#box3 {
    top: 250px;
    left: 200px;
}
#line1 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}
#line2 {
    top: 220px;
    left: 150px;
    height: 115px;

    transform: rotate(120deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to include -webkit-transform:rotate(120deg); for those not using IE

Comment: Updated with prefixes for IE 9 and webkit.

Comment: Would this work on mobile devices?

Comment: @marsone It should http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Answer (score 3):

Definitely possible with any number of libraries and/or HTML5 technologies. You could possible hack something together in pure CSS by using something like the border-bottom property, but it would probably be horribly hacky.

If you're serious about this, you should take a look at a JS library for canvas drawing or SVG. For example, something like http://www.graphjs.org/ or http://jsdraw2dx.jsfiction.com/

Comment: But when I use Canvas I cannot bind events on the objects?

Comment: Depends exactly what you want to do. If you're concerned with mouse clicks you can get access to the mouseMove and click events and compare current mouse position to the position of elements in the canvas. There are lots of 2d and 3d canvas/webGL sketches which respond to mouse/keyboard events. I just did another random google search and found http://sigmajs.org/ which looks really nice and has a responsive demo on their front page.

Answer (score 3):

Check my fiddle from this thread: [Draw a line connecting two clicked div columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927663/draw-a-line-connecting-two-clicked-div-columns/23950589#23950589)

The layout is different, but basically the idea is to create invisible divs between the boxes and add corresponding borders with jQuery (the answer is only HTML and CSS)

Answer (score 2):

Create a div that is the line with the code like this:

CSS

```
div#lineHorizontal {
    background-color: #000;
    width: //the width of the line or how far it goes sidewards;
    height: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
 }
div#block {
    background-color: #777;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="block">
</div>
<div id="lineHorizontal">
</div>
<div id="block">
</div>
```

This will display a block with a horizontal line to another block.

On mobile devices you could use (caniuse.com/transforms2d)

Comment: This doesn't display blocks or a line if run as is.