# How to join boxed menu items with a line using CSS

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am wondering if there's a way to join boxed menu items with a line using CSS? See picture. I am using wordpress.

What do you think?

Many thanks

Guillaume

[image: Menu with line between items]

Comment: I think this thread may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382872/how-to-connect-html-divs-with-lines

Comment: try this http://plnkr.co/edit/JgS6EwOUTaiV9UfyOXr1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Surya Singh, it worked like a dream.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the containing div a background image that has the line. It'll appear behind the buttons, so as long as you give the buttons a background color of black, it might work.