# customized css for advanced list site hierarchy view

Tags: css, list, sitemap

I want to customize a list (that has my site hierarchy) to look like this image shared below. any ideas if it is doable using CSS? or there is another way
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a line between two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-divs)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is doable. The first step is to generate and position the blocks containing the page names, and of course style them with CSS.

The tricky part is the connecting lines. From a quick search it seems this is possible with just HTML and CSS, but there will be libraries out there to achieve the same result. Check out these other questions on the matter:

[6278152](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-draggable-divs)

[19382872](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382872/how-to-connect-html-divs-with-lines)

If you share some more information on what environment you're working with in terms of generating the HTML components, we can maybe look at assisting with some coding examples.

Comment: I am using kentico cms and I configured my sitemap.xml file but since it is not user friendly I wanted to give my hierarchy another style