# How to draw a line connector between two icons displayed in two different div.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have displayed one Icons in one Div element. I need to draw a connecting line between those Icons. Please note that the Div is a dynamic element.

I have displayed the current Image below. 
[image]

Expected image is displayed below.

[image]

Please guide me how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/ this might help you

Comment: something similar to this already asked link for it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382872/how-to-connect-html-divs-with-lines(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382872/how-to-connect-html-divs-with-lines)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect HTML Divs with Lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382872/how-to-connect-html-divs-with-lines)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small demo that will help you know how to use [jsPlumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com) achieve what you want.

```js
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
            jsPlumb.connect({
                source:"firstItem",
                target:"secondItem",
                endpoint:"Dot"
            });
        });
```

```css
span{
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
     <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/1.4.1/jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.1-all-min.js"></script>
 <div id="diagramContainer">
        <div  >
        <span id="firstItem">Smiley1</span>
        </div>
        <div >
         <span style="float:right" id="secondItem">Smiley2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: How about multiple elements? more than two.

Comment: @bhansa thats also possible you can go through the docs for more details. Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 2):

The concept is to draw a div with absolute position inside of "starting point" and rotate it on an angle between 2 points:

```
// a,b  = jquery results i.e. a=$('#smile1'), b=$('#smile2'),
  function dist(a,b) {
      let o1 = a.offset(), o2 = b.offset();
       return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(o1.top  - o2.top,2) + Math.pow(o1.left - o2.left,2));
    }
    function angle(a, b) {
       let ao = a.offset(), bo = b.offset();
           dx = ao.left-bo.left, dy = ao.top-bo.top;
       return Math.PI + Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    }
    function drawConnection(a,b) {
       $('.line').remove();
       let d = dist(a,b);
       a.removeClass('first');
       let ang = d<10 
           ? 0
           : (angle(a,b) * 180)/ Math.PI;
       a.append(
          $('<div>').addClass('line')
              .css({
                  width: Math.round(d) +'px',
                  transform: 'rotate(' + Math.round(ang) + 'deg)'
              })
       );
       return ang;
    }
```

CSS for the line should be:

```
.line {
   position: absolute;
   transform-origin: top left; // to make it rotate around top-left
   border-top: solid 2px blue; // set any color
   top: 10px; // center of your "smile"
   left: 10px;
}
```

Here is the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/oppin/kpahmwL8/)

Comment: Appreciate your efforts. This is quite helpful. But i don't want to select the two icons to connect them. I want them to be connected on page load itself. Any suggestions please?

Comment: as I wrote, simply select those two icons on page load.
if you have jquery enabled you can copypaste this code and add to the bottom drawConnection($('$id_of_icon1'),$('$id_of_icon2'));