# how to connect two div based on id?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a dynamic block diagram where each block has a different id, and want has to be connected like shown in below diagram;

[image]

I saw another similar post with a solution

```
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>
<div class="box" id="box3"></div>

<div class="line" id="line1"></div>
<div class="line" id="line2"></div>
```

but here the problem is the diagram is not static and the block and the connection are made from the data recieved from backend.

Comment: I would recommend to look through https://d3js.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect HTML Divs with Lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382872/how-to-connect-html-divs-with-lines)

Comment: That solution works, you just have to add some logic to customize it