# Image Caption with line to Another div

Tags: javascript, html, image, css

Exist some JS or CSS to make line over a image (in one div) and automatics link with another div ?

Red boxes are DIV and orange lines whats i will do.

I tried to make the rectangles but this do only in the main box ( wo is the image)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you could modify your question and provide more details along with the code, then it would be more easy for anyone here to help you out.

Comment: some like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382872/how-to-connect-html-divs-with-lines   but from a div with image and the circle (orange) is inner DIV .