# Draw a line from one element to multiple elements on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to draw a line from an element [.identifier] to the clicked element [ A, B, C series ]. I'm able to display the line but in the other direction, not sure why it is displaying in such a direction.
Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SampathPerOxide/u2afymxs/11/
Can someone help me to display a line between ".identifier" and the respective series element?

Expected result on clicking A series:
[image]
on clicking B series:
[image]

```js
$('.seriesli').click(function() {

  function adjustLine(from, to, line) {

    var fT = from.offsetTop + from.offsetHeight / 2;
    var tT = to.offsetTop + to.offsetHeight / 2;
    var fL = from.offsetLeft + from.offsetWidth / 2;
    var tL = to.offsetLeft + to.offsetWidth / 2;

    var CA = Math.abs(tT - fT);
    var CO = Math.abs(tL - fL);
    var H = Math.sqrt(CA * CA + CO * CO);
    var ANG = 180 / Math.PI * Math.acos(CA / H);

    if (tT > fT) {
      var top = (tT - fT) / 2 + fT;
    } else {
      var top = (fT - tT) / 2 + tT;
    }
    if (tL > fL) {
      var left = (tL - fL) / 2 + fL;
    } else {
      var left = (fL - tL) / 2 + tL;
    }

    if ((fT < tT && fL < tL) || (tT < fT && tL < fL) || (fT > tT && fL > tL) || (tT > fT && tL > fL)) {
      ANG *= -1;
    }
    top -= H / 2;

    line.style["-webkit-transform"] = 'rotate(' + ANG + 'deg)';
    line.style["-moz-transform"] = 'rotate(' + ANG + 'deg)';
    line.style["-ms-transform"] = 'rotate(' + ANG + 'deg)';
    line.style["-o-transform"] = 'rotate(' + ANG + 'deg)';
    line.style["-transform"] = 'rotate(' + ANG + 'deg)';
    line.style.top = top + 'px';
    line.style.left = left + 'px';
    line.style.height = H + 'px';
  }
  adjustLine(
    document.getElementById('div1'),
    document.getElementById('div2'),
    document.getElementById('line')
  );
});
```

```css
.identifier {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 45%;
  top: 50%;
}

.series-div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 30%;
}

.series-ul li {
  list-style: none;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display: table;
  padding: 0.3em 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position;relative;">
  <div class="identifier" id="div2"></div>
  <div class="series-div">
    <ul class="series-ul">
      <li class="seriesli" id="div1">A series</li>

      <li class="seriesli">B series</li>
  
      <li class="seriesli">C series</li>
    
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div id="line"></div>
  <img src="https://stat.overdrive.in/wp-content/odgallery/2020/06/57263_2020_Mercedes_Benz_GLS.jpg" class="img-responsive firstcar-detail" style="width: 100%;">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you expand the variable names? Variables like `fT`, `tT`, etc are hard to make sense of.

Comment: Those are just short forms, fT- fromTop, tT - toTop, fL - fromLet, tL - toLeft, etc. I took the code from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382872/how-to-connect-html-divs-with-lines/36045181#36045181

Comment: Your image is responsive, but the .identifier is positioned absolutely. Is the .identifier supposed to point to a specific point on the car image?

Comment: Yes, the '.identifier' is supposed to point the car front window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c4ju6a0p/

**Code changes:**

```
// Get actual position relative to viewport.
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/117030
fromBCR = from.getBoundingClientRect();
toBCR   = to.getBoundingClientRect();

var fT = fromBCR.top + from.offsetHeight / 2;
var tT = toBCR.top + to.offsetHeight / 2;

// Don't add offsetWidth. This connects to the middle, not the left edge.
var fL = fromBCR.left //+ from.offsetWidth / 2;
var tL = toBCR.left + to.offsetWidth / 2;
```

---

- The problem was the line was being calculated with the incorrect position due to `relative` positioning. This can be seen more clearly when the `relative` CSS is commented out: https://jsfiddle.net/vust5nxf/
- Also, don't add the `offsetWidth` if you want the line to go to the left edge.

---

**update:** didn't notice the code snippet... applied changes there, too. I also made one more change:

- You need to pass the element that was clicked to `adjustLine()`, otherwise currently the line is drawn between the same two elements every time because the elements are hardcoded with ids.
- As a style note: I would move the definition of function `adjustLine()` outside the click handler. This will make the code easier to read, and the function will only be created once, instead of every time a click is handled.

```
adjustLine(
  this, // Element that was clicked.
  document.getElementById('div2'),
  document.getElementById('line')
);
```

```js
$('.seriesli').click(function() {

  function adjustLine(from, to, line) {

    // Get actual position relative to viewport.
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/117030
    fromBCR = from.getBoundingClientRect();
    toBCR   = to.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    var fT = fromBCR.top + from.offsetHeight / 2;
    var tT = toBCR.top + to.offsetHeight / 2;
    
    // Don't add offsetWidth. This connects to the middle, not the left edge.
    var fL = fromBCR.left //+ from.offsetWidth / 2;
    var tL = toBCR.left + to.offsetWidth / 2;

    var CA = Math.abs(tT - fT);
    var CO = Math.abs(tL - fL);
    var H = Math.sqrt(CA * CA + CO * CO);
    var ANG = 180 / Math.PI * Math.acos(CA / H);

    if (tT > fT) {
      var top = (tT - fT) / 2 + fT;
    } else {
      var top = (fT - tT) / 2 + tT;
    }
    if (tL > fL) {
      var left = (tL - fL) / 2 + fL;
    } else {
      var left = (fL - tL) / 2 + tL;
    }

    if ((fT < tT && fL < tL) || (tT < fT && tL < fL) || (fT > tT && fL > tL) || (tT > fT && tL > fL)) {
      ANG *= -1;
    }
    top -= H / 2;

    line.style["-webkit-transform"] = 'rotate(' + ANG + 'deg)';
    line.style["-moz-transform"] = 'rotate(' + ANG + 'deg)';
    line.style["-ms-transform"] = 'rotate(' + ANG + 'deg)';
    line.style["-o-transform"] = 'rotate(' + ANG + 'deg)';
    line.style["-transform"] = 'rotate(' + ANG + 'deg)';
    line.style.top = top + 'px';
    line.style.left = left + 'px';
    line.style.height = H + 'px';
  }
  adjustLine(
    this, // Element that was clicked.
    document.getElementById('div2'),
    document.getElementById('line')
  );
});
```

```css
.identifier {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 45%;
  top: 50%;
}

.series-div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 30%;
}

.series-ul li {
  list-style: none;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display: table;
  padding: 0.3em 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position;relative;">
  <div class="identifier" id="div2"></div>
  <div class="series-div">
    <ul class="series-ul">
      <li class="seriesli" id="div1">A series</li>

      <li class="seriesli">B series</li>
  
      <li class="seriesli">C series</li>
    
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div id="line"></div>
  <img src="https://stat.overdrive.in/wp-content/odgallery/2020/06/57263_2020_Mercedes_Benz_GLS.jpg" class="img-responsive firstcar-detail" style="width: 100%;">

</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Leftium, the code is perfectly working alone, but when I'm trying to integrate the code, the lines are generating at different place, the coordinates of the elements are not identifying properly, I used position relative to parent elements to align few elements, is it because of that the lines are disturbed when I embed the code in my page? Please have a look at my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SampathPerOxide/jdyoz3r4/

Comment: @Sampath I'm not sure. There were a lot of changes. I suggest starting with the working version, and keep adding one new element at a time to isolate the problem.

Comment: I tried with working version and added each element and figured out that few div's are causing the issue, I commented out those HTML div's and it's working fine, but not sure why those other div's are causing the issue. Here is the fiddle with commented HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/SampathPerOxide/kqfjvs04/  .Can you check why the lines are disturbing with those div's?