# Create line between two images in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to write with `jQuery` in `html`. Hence when a user click any one  of the shown image, a line between them will be appeared. I found a lot of info about " how to do it in canvas",and I found  it is possible to just use the images in `html` file. 
For example when clicked on id1 and the id4 a line appears that connects them.

Comment: Can you put a separator image in between and make it visible on any of image click?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kDs2Q/45/?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a line between two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-divs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thanks to @LastCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672369/how-to-draw-a-line-between-two-divs):

This won't work in IE8 or below due to CSS restrictions. It uses pure Javascript, no need for jQuery.

```
function getOffset( el ) { // return element top, left, width, height
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    var _w = el.offsetWidth|0;
    var _h = el.offsetHeight|0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x, width: _w, height: _h };
}

function connect(div1, div2, color, thickness) { // draw a line connecting elements
    var off1 = getOffset(div1);
    var off2 = getOffset(div2);
    // bottom right
    var x1 = off1.left + off1.width;
    var y1 = off1.top + off1.height;
    // top right
    var x2 = off2.left + off2.width;
    var y2 = off2.top;
    // distance
    var length = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1) * (x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1) * (y2-y1)));
    // center
    var cx = ((x1 + x2) / 2) - (length / 2);
    var cy = ((y1 + y2) / 2) - (thickness / 2);
    // angle
    var angle = Math.atan2((y1-y2),(x1-x2))*(180/Math.PI);
    // make hr
    var htmlLine = "<div style='padding:0px; margin:0px; height:" + thickness + "px; background-color:" + color + "; line-height:1px; position:absolute; left:" + cx + "px; top:" + cy + "px; width:" + length + "px; -moz-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -o-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -ms-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg);' />";
    //
    // alert(htmlLine);
    document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine;
}
```

Simply call it by using something like:

```
<a onclick="testIt();">Draw line</a>

window.testIt = function() {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('div2')
    connect(div1, div2, "#0F0", 2);
}
```

[Here is the working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/kDs2Q/45/)

Answer (score 0):

I think Using HTML-5 you can do this.Please try this link.[Html-5](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html)