# How to add line(arrows) in between element (Input Field)?

Tags: javascript, html

Here I am trying to visualize a sequence diagram and I want to add some arrows using JavaSript.
How can I add?

I tried this - [Draw lines between 2 elements in html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864989/draw-lines-between-2-elements-in-html-page)

In this case, all element becoming disable (because canvas coming in front)[image]

eg: arrow from an input field of the verifier to an input field of the prover vice versa.

Comment: Put the canvas *behind* the interface.

Comment: I tried but nothing worked.

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you suggest some other reference?

Comment: If you put the canvas behind the other elements, it won't prevent the user from clicking on them. You can also use `pointer-events`