# Get live position of two div and update connecting line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've recently followed this example but I'm struggling to get the live position of div's and updating the connecting line with the relevant position.

Lines connecting to responsive elements

Example of my work here
https://jsfiddle.net/spencer1997/vktg31e2/24/

[How to draw a line between two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672369/how-to-draw-a-line-between-two-divs)

Need it to be something like this :

```
$('.btn').animate({ 'margin-left':'200px', 'margin-top':'70px'}, 3000)

setInterval(function(){
 var div = $('.btn').offset();
 $( ".live-position" ).text( "left: " + div.left + ", top: " + div.top );
}, 100);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rpgpp2mp/

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry but in your fiddle, i just see one div which moves and the other?

Comment: Hi Sorry please use this Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/spencer1997/vktg31e2/24/

Answer (score 0):

this shall do the trick, it relies on maths essentially, if you want to change teh position either of the line or the text, you have to change the top and left value so that the angle is still valid and add an offset top and left

```js
$('.btn').animate({ 'margin-left':'200px', 'margin-top':'70px'}, 3000)

const int = setInterval(function(){
 const btn = $('.btn').offset();
 $( ".live-position" ).text( "left: " + btn.left + ", top: " + btn.top );
 const line = document.getElementById("line")
 const angle = Math.atan(btn.top / btn.left);
 line.style.transform = `rotateZ(${angle}rad)`;
 line.style.width=`${Math.sqrt(Math.pow(btn.top, 2)+Math.pow(btn.left, 2))}px`
 
}, 100);

setTimeout(() => clearInterval(int), 3000)
```

```css
#line {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 2px;
  width: 5em;
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
}

.btn {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>position: <p class="live-position"></p></div>
<div class="btn">text</div>
<span id="line"></span>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll try to implement that into my work, a rough example of it is below.
https://jsfiddle.net/spencer1997/vktg31e2/24/