# How to draw the diagonal line between two div's

Tags: html, css, canvas, transient, skew

How to draw this diagonal line between these two div's ABC and XYZ

```
<div class="row">
<div class="abc">abc</div>
<div class="xys">xyz</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [How to make a line through a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672369/how-to-draw-a-line-between-two-divs).

Another way you could do it is by making another div and use positioning and rotation like this:

```css
#div-with-line {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#line {
  width: 280px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  right: 39px;
  top: 99px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-with-line">
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>
```

It makes a line through the div, but you have to change the positioning every time you change the width or the height of the box.

Comment: Am trying to add diagonal line which will start from first div left 0 and cross between both divs and then second divs top then goes faded like tilt

Comment: So you are trying to do an animation? Sounds very complicated. Have you tried doing svg animations? Do some research on that. I think that would be more of what you are looking for. Its actually very simple.

Comment: No jot animation fixed diagonal line as in image white thin