# drag and drop palette UI and connecting objects in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am looking to design an UI which allows to drag elements which can be able to connect one another from a palette to a html canvas.

Can any one tell is there any predefined library to achieve this or an approach to start this.

Comment: This would be an off-topic question for SO (asking for external resources). Voting to close.

Comment: As K3N says, your question is off-topic for Stackoverflow where we typically answer questions on existing code. **Starting hints:** This previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656003/html5-drag-and-drop-images-from-a-toolbar-to-a-canvas) shows how to drop/copy an img element onto canvas. Connecting the dropped images can be done by 1. Clearing the canvas, 2. Drawing path lines between the centerpoints of images that need to be connected using `context.lineTo`, 3. Redrawing the images on the canvas.