# Drag Drop Feature and Arrow Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, actionscript, kineticjs

I intend to make a flowchart tool which if feasible will use a drag and drop feature, such as drag a rhombus, oval, diamond box etc. and the arrows that can connect them.

Can anyone please suggest proper language to begin which can support features like defining objects for rectangle, arrows, and there mapping so that i know a particular arrow is pointing to a rectangle with ID xyz....

I am tagging this question with jquery, javascript,actionscript...some libraries that i know by name not by technical expertise if in case they do support what i am looking for.

Please suggest.

Comment: I would go for old fashioned HTML, CSS and jQuery. If you feel more skilled you could look at https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/ (2D) or http://threejs.org/ (3D)

Comment: @NinjaFart: Could you code up a quick illustration of a couple of divs being connected by a line with arrows on each end of the line with one of the divs being draggable?

Comment: This question would have been better addressed to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (just publicizing an excellent SE site). You might have gotten a more satisfactory response, rather than a staring point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a line between two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-divs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is meant as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/Qgt9V/2/

```
$( ".box-handle" ).draggable({ 
    containment: ".container", 
    scroll: false, 
    drag: function () { /* While dragging check for stuff */

        var box = $(this);
        var boxPosition = box.position();
        box.find('.arrow').show();

        if (boxPosition.left >= 90)
        {
            // In the parent div called ".box" find ".box-line"
            box.closest('.box').find('.box-line').css({
                'top':'50px', /* Put top left corner of ".box-line" a the edge of ".static" */
                'left':'110px',
                'width': boxPosition.left - 60, /* Put bottom right corner of ".box-line" a the edge of current dragged box */
                'height': boxPosition.top + 50,
                'border':'none',
                'border-top':'1px solid #bfbfbf',
                'border-right':'1px solid #bfbfbf'
            });
            /* place the arrow*/
            box.find('.arrow').css({
                'top':'-10px',
                'left':'45px'
            });
        }
        else if (boxPosition.left < 90)
        {
            box.closest('.box').find('.box-line').css({
                'top':'110px',
                'left':'50px',
                'width': boxPosition.left,
                'height': boxPosition.top - 60,
                'border':'none',
                'border-left':'1px solid #bfbfbf',
                'border-bottom':'1px solid #bfbfbf'
            });
            box.find('.arrow').css({
                'top':'45px',
                'left':'-10px'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I'm using jQuery UI draggable for moving div's around. While moving the div "box-line" resizes itself according to the position of the box I'm dragging. Then it's just a matter of adding borders to the correct side of "box-line".

- [More about draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/).
- Also have a look at [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and/or [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) methods.

Answer (score 0):

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-draggable-divs), which references the excellent [JsPlumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com).

The toolkit edition includes drag and drop in the community edition and actually has a [demo flowchart app](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demos/toolkit/flowchart-builder/index.html) in the (very expensive) toolkit edition.

In fact the community edition fully answers your question. Take a look at the [perimeter anchors demo](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/perimeterAnchors/index.html).